# Why we do acf on residuals?

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, diagnostic, acf-pacf

In the book "Time series analysis" by Shumway.

He is doing

```
fit = lm(chicken~time(chicken), na.action=NULL) 
acf(resid(fit), 48, main="detrended")
```

What is the point of doing acf on residuals? I do see the point in acf for the data itself... But what's the use doing it for the residuals?

Comment: My analysis at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/35524/919 applies to this one-dimensional case, too.  It shows how trends in the data affect the apparent autocorrelation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a linear time trend there'd be little point in doing the acf on the raw data; it would be dominated by the common time trend, rather than correlation in the error terms and it would be stronger for a longer series, even though the actual dependence was the same.

I don't think that we're looking at the same edition of the same book (you should give a full reference), but I see the discussion of this data set in the one I have.

Shuway and Stoffer say:

> *There is an obvious upward
>   trend in the series, and we might use simple linear regression to estimate that trend
>   by fitting the model*

then later

> *In general, it is necessary for time series data to be stationary so that averaging
>   lagged products over time, as in the previous section, will be a sensible thing to
>   do. With time series data, it is the dependence between the values of the series that
>   is important to measure; we must, at least, be able to estimate autocorrelations with
>   precision. It would be difficult to measure that dependence if the dependence structure
>   is not regular or is changing at every time point. Hence, to achieve any meaningful
>   statistical analysis of time series data, it will be crucial that, if nothing else, the mean
>   and the autocovariance functions satisfy the conditions of stationarity*

and then

> *as we suggested in the analysis of the chicken price data presented in
>   Example 2.1, a straight line might be useful for detrending the data; i.e.,*

I believe these quotes from the text provide a complete account for why they acted as they did - they remove the estimated linear trend to attempt to achieve mean-variance stationarity (weak stationarity).

They then go on to look at differencing rather than removing a linear trend, and discuss why that might be a better choice.